# Implement LTI tool consumer in java

Tags: java, canvas-lms, lti

I'm working on an E-learning project, I need to add Quiz to a school platform.

I found QTIWorks to implement the questions, QTIWorks contain LTI provider so I try connect with it through Moodle and it is working.

now I need to make my platform as tool consumer to connect with QTIWorks, my platform is coded with java, so I'm searching for an example to implement tool consumer in java but I can't find.

so, How I can implement tool consumer in my platform please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sakai is a tool consumer implemented in java, so you might look at their source code: [Sakai github page](https://github.com/sakaiproject/sakai)

But you will probably find the most useful information about implementing a tool consumer by looking at the [LTI 1.2 implementation guide](http://www.imsglobal.org/lti/ltiv1p2/ltiIMGv1p2.html)